# Bootstrap 4: text-center & aligned left?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Goal:**  I'd like the text to be aligned to the left but center of the screen using Bootstrap 4.

Example:

```
                       This text is centered
                       And aligned left
```

I've tried wrapping the text in a parent like below however it is not currently working.

```css
#text{
font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
<p id='text'> This text is aligned left but not centered  </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are u expecting like this https://jsfiddle.net/js80zcao/

Comment: Try setting the font size to be 20px and expanding the viewport to full in your example

Answer (score 1):

Just set a width size that you're looking for ( or use bootstrap sizes ).

```
p{
   width: 300px;
   font-size: 50px;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9eaxhy01/

Comment: How would this be responsive?

Comment: Take out the ( width 300px ) and insert col. xs or whatever you want for the width of the container. Example https://jsfiddle.net/4makrtn7/

Comment: My goal is to have the "1 of 2" be in the center of that outline

Comment: you want the text inside the container to be centered and then left aligned? In whatever scenario you're trying, just use margin: 0 auto; to center the text or container and then text-align: left;

Answer (score 0):

Because you use 2x div and style. First div is always property takes precedence.